# How to Group by and concatenate arrays in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL. I want to concatenate all the arrays(i.e. `col`) after grouping them by `time`. The arrays are of varying dimensions.

```
| time  | col               |
|------ |------------------ |
| 1     | {1,2}             |
| 1     | {3,4,5,6}         |
| 2     | {}                |
| 2     | {7}               |
| 2     | {8,9,10}          |
| 3     | {11,12,13,14,15}  |
```

The result should be as follows:

```
| time  | col               |
|------ |------------------ |
| 1     | {1,2,3,4,5,6}     |
| 2     | {7,8,9,10}        |
| 3     | {11,12,13,14,15}  |
```

What I have come up with so far is as follows:

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT elem FROM tab, unnest(col) elem);
```

But this does not do the grouping. It just takes the entire table and concatenates it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To preserve the same dimension of you array you can't directly use `array_agg()`, so first we `unnest` your arrays and apply `distinct` to remove duplicates (1). In outer query this is the time to aggregate. To preserve values ordering include `order by` within aggregate function:

```
select time, array_agg(col order by col) as col
from (
  select distinct time, unnest(col) as col
  from yourtable
) t
group by time
order by time
```

(1) If you don't need duplicate removal just remove `distinct` word.

Comment: This is removing duplicates from the arrays too.

Comment: You, sir, are a legend. Thank you so much for the simple and elegant query.

Answer (score 1):

you can use next query

```
 SELECT 
      array_agg(_unnested.item) as array_coll
 from my_table
 left join LATERAL (SELECT unnest(my_table.array_coll) as item) _unnested ON TRUE
```