# postgres sql window function - trying to consolidate array_agg based on date and employee_id

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, window-functions, array-agg

I am currently using postgres and there is this sql window function that is used to generate employee check in and out time based on date. But its flawed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_test
 AS
 SELECT row_number() OVER () AS id,
    a.created_at::date AS created_at,
    date_part('year'::text, a.created_at) AS year,
    date_part('month'::text, a.created_at) AS month,
    date_part('day'::text, a.created_at) AS day,
    date_part('dow'::text, a.created_at) AS dow,
    a.company_id,
    a.employee_id,
    e.employee_type,
    array_agg(
        CASE
            WHEN a.activity_type = 1
            THEN a.created_at::time(0) 
            ELSE NULL::time
        END) AS time_in,
    array_agg(
        CASE
            WHEN a.activity_type = 2 
            THEN a.created_at::time(0) 
            ELSE NULL::time
        END) AS time_out
   FROM attendance_table a
     LEFT JOIN employee_table e ON e.id = a.employee_id
  GROUP BY a.created_at, date_part('day'::text, a.created_at),  
           a.employee_id, a.company_id, e.employee_type
  ORDER BY date_part('year'::text, a.created_at), date_part('month'::text, a.created_at), 
           date_part('day'::text, a.created_at), a.employee_id;
```

this generate this result

[image: generates this data]

I am trying to generate this way where time_in and time_out is consolidated based on created_at (date) and employee_id. The idea is for each date, I would know the employee check in and out times. caveat: {NULL} should not appear if there are records in the array.

[image: trying to generate this data]

view and fields of the data I am trying to manipulate

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hn3w0mnezrV6_f-fPAKPZHuqdDjBBc_ArcgeBmgblq4/edit?usp=sharing

How can I modify the windows function sql view above so that the time_in and time_out is consolidated based on the created_at (date) and employee_id ? (the last screenshot is the desired output) caveat: {NULL} should not appear if there are records in the array.

**UPDATE (very close answer but not quite solved):**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_group
 as 
 SELECT
    created_at,
    year,
    month,
    day,
    dow,
    company_id,
    employee_id,
    array_agg(check_in) as time_in,
    array_agg(check_out) as time_out
FROM
    view_test, unnest(time_in) check_in, unnest(time_out) check_out
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

it produces this:

[image: almost there]

manage to concatenate the array by unnest. But notice NULL is still there. How do I remove NULL (but if there is nothing, NULL should be there) ? or something that make sense and possible.

Comment: Please add the original data. Furthermore please don't use images, because it is not possible to copy data from the images for own tests.

Comment: Why do you want to return arrays of time instead of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your original data I can only work with your current result.

To transform your result into the expected one, you can simple add a group step:

```
SELECT
    created_at,
    year,
    month,
    day,
    dow,
    company_id,
    employee_id,
    MAX(time_in) as time_in,
    MAX(time_out) as time_out
FROM
    -- <your query>
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

---

**Edit**: TO added original data

You need a simple pivot step. This can be achieved using a conditional aggregation (`GROUP BY` and `FILTER` clauses):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c96021a662cd5f2287953ac28b28ef9f)

```
SELECT 
    created_at::date,
    company_id,
    employee_id,
    MAX(created_at::time) FILTER (WHERE activity_type = 1),
    MAX(created_at::time) FILTER (WHERE activity_type = 2)
FROM
   attendance
GROUP BY created_at::date, company_id, employee_id
```

Comment: I'ved put that information on example data & fields in here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hn3w0mnezrV6_f-fPAKPZHuqdDjBBc_ArcgeBmgblq4/edit?usp=sharing. I'd like to use the same SQL statement as shown above to avoid massive code changes. are you saying that the original query is inserted into "<your query>

Comment: I did a test, it worked in a way, date and employee_id is grouped. there is no additional rows based on these 2 fields. but time_in and time_out are not consolidated, both time_in and time_out result appears as {NULL}. This is the next important field where I need to consolidate all the grouped results

Comment: (also {NULL}) should NOT appear if there is data in the array). Maybe there is way to remove NULL at the initial view.

Comment: I found something a bit close to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101596/how-to-group-by-and-concatenate-arrays-in-postgresql. However, the example given is distinct on one field, while I would like to group by for 2 fields (date(created_at) and employee_id)

Comment: Maybe use array_agg(time_in) ? but it complaints - "could not find array type for data type time without time zone[]"

Comment: Added a solution based on your original data

Comment: Thanks. I like the pivot solution.